# Calling function at the end of setInterval

Tags: jquery, css

I want set opacity back to 1.

```
 setInterval(function() {
    $('li:first')
    .animate({ opacity: "0" }, 1000, function() { $(this).hide(); })
    .next().show()
    .end().appendTo('ul');
  }, 5000);
```

I can do all steps after animation, like below. It's doing exactly what I want, but it's a really bad idea.

```
setInterval(function() {
   $('li:first')
   .animate({ opacity: "0" }, 1000, function() { 
      $(this).hide();
      $(this).next().show();
      $(this).appendTo("ul");
      $(this).css("opacity", "1")})
}, 5000);
```

Comment: CSS animation happens on browser events like hover,focus etc. not on setInterval.

Comment: jQuery's `end()` is to end the filter chaining. it has nothing to do with `animate` or `setInterval`

Answer (score -1):

How about using CSS transitions and toggling classes (with jQuery) to animate hiding and showing elements?

```
foo{transition: opacity 1s}

.hide{opacity: 0; visibility: hidden;}
.show{opacity: 1; visibility: visible;}
```

Now with jQuery simply toggle the hide and show classes

```
$(foo).removeClass("show").addClass("hide") 
$(foo).removeClass("hide").addClass("show")
```

Or using vanilla JavaScript (less compatible)

```
foo.classList.toggle("hide")
foo.classList.toggle("show")
```

Comment: Where is the CSS transition in your example? :|

Comment: Any element which could be animated should have it's transition property already set in css :)